# Symfony2 : customize form element IDs in form collections

Tags: symfony

When using form collections, form element IDs are automatically constructed by sf2

**Form/WeekType.php**

```php
class WeekType extends AbstractType
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return "MyBundle";
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('fixtures', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new FixtureType(),
        ));
    }
 }
```

**Form/FixtureType.php**

```php
class FixtureType extends AbstractType
{  
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('score1', 'text');
    }
}
```

This code produces following form elements:

```html
<select id="MyBundle_fixtures_0_score1" />
<select id="MyBundle_fixtures_1_score1" />
```

0, 1... are just the current iteration index.

I want to change the ids of select tags. For example, putting primary key values (from Model) instead of iteration index.

```html
<select id="MyBundle_fixtures_151_score1" />
<select id="MyBundle_fixtures_152_score1" />
```

or even:

```html
<select id="MyBundle_fixtures_0_score1_151" />
<select id="MyBundle_fixtures_1_score1_152" />
```

151, 152 are the primary key value from Fixture table (from database).

Answer (score 1):

You can add "**indexBy**" annotation for *OneToMany* relation column (fixtures) in your entity class or use *INDEX BY* keyword in the DQL:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Entity", mappedBy="ref", indexBy="id")
 */
private $fixtures;
```

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/working-with-indexed-associations.html

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways to do this:

- You can modify yourself keys of the collections passed to the form, for example create a new collection with ids instead of keys.
- You can modify the [ResizeFormListener](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/EventListener/ResizeFormListener.php#L123) to use ids instead of keys.

Comment: Your last proposal is still under [discussion](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/1461).

Regarding your first proposal, I don't get it. How can I modify collections keys passed to the form?